# How do I filter a javascript gantt chart using conditions and handle empty inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtmlx

I've recently started using the [DHTMLX javascript based Gantt chart](https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/).  I'm having some issues with the filters which I don't feel are exclusively related to the chart itself, but, related to javascript.

So, the Gantt [chart can be filtered](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__filtering.html) by passing in some conditions via an `if` statement and returning `true` when those conditions are met.  All my conditions values come from a selection of inputs, these inputs represent ranges.

```
<input type="text" class="k-textbox" id="bedsStart" />
<input type="text" class="k-textbox" id="bedsEnd" />

<input type="text" class="k-textbox" id="deckStart" />
<input type="text" class="k-textbox" id="deckEnd" />

<button type="button" id="filterSort">Set Filters</button>
```

When you click on the filter button the on click event is triggered and the values are gathered from the input fields.

```
$("#filterSort").on("click", function (e) {        
    let bedsStart = $('#bedsStart').val();
    let bedsEnd = $('#bedsEnd').val();
    let deckStart = $('#deckStart').val();
    let deckEnd = $('#deckEnd').val();
```

These values are then passed as conditions to the filter as per the documentation from DHTMLX:

```
    gantt.attachEvent("onBeforeTaskDisplay", function (id, task) {
        if (task.crane >= craneStart && task.crane <= craneEnd) {
            return true
        }        
        return false;
    });
    gantt.init("ganttReport");
}
```

The problem is if any of the text inputs are empty/null then the filter fails and returns nothing.  Is there a way I can handle these nulls values by not including them or dynamically specify what filters to use?

The filter seems to only be capable of returning `true` or `false` so having multiple `if` statements don't work as it's always the last statement that will deliver an outcome with the previous iterations being overwritten i.e.

```
if(condition1)
{
    return true
}
if(condition2)
{
    return true
}
return false
```

The above code wouldn't work and only condition2 would be used as condition1 would be overwritten.  So I can't just set out my conditions in this manner or using `if else`.

Can anyone offer a solution to how I can pass all these conditions to this single statement yet handle the nulls?

Comment: I have added an example below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working example, you can try with only startDate/endDate or both:
https://codesandbox.io/s/7qz1kw9vq